# Border Radius on Image Transforms

Tags: image-transforms

Is it possible to add a border-radius to an Image Transform?

I'm using circular profile photos for a client. I could do the radius in CSS, but it'd be nice for the image to output with the radius.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just crop it with CSS, as you alluded to. https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/web-design/circular-images-css/

Comment: I created profile pages for my client's staff, then used routes to create custom email signatures for them based on their profile info... "border-radius" doesn't work on all e-mail clients, so I was trying to figure out a work-around.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It's probably doable via a custom plugin.